# Exporting posts from a Facebook-event to a group

Tags: facebook, facebook-events, export-to-text

My friend recently passed away and me and another friend was asked to estimate how many people would come to the funeral. I did this by creating an event, inviting those we thought would want to come. On the event-page people started sharing their memories through text and pictures. This was nice for everyone involved, but the question now is there any way to export these posts? It's would be sad to just see them fade with the event.

As far as I can see there's no way to share the posts to another group, nor convert to event to a group.

If anyone could suggest another way to this, either through code or a Facebook functionality I would be grateful.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/event/feed

Comment: Thanks! I guess I have to read up and try my way, but will this export directly to a group?

Comment: not sure what you mean, that is the graph api and you will get json data. there is no way to export stuff directly to a group, you would need to use the api to get the entries and then use the api to post stuff in the group. check out the api docs for that too.